# What does "...you would rather we have the meeting..." mean?

Tags: grammar

I recently received an email which had a sentence:

> "Let us know if you would rather we have the meeting next week with
>   just Alisa and Bob."

This grammar ("you would rather we have") looks weird to me. I would just say "Let us know if you would rather like us to have a meeting...". Yet the person who wrote is a native speaker and insisted that people actually use it all the time. Can anyone explain how to use it and give more examples?

Comment: I use that form all the time. Your example sounds more like "Let us know if you would **especially** like use to have a meeting..." which has a completely different connotation.

Comment: The following question seems more related, [Is 'I would rather…' without an infinitive immediately following it correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73891/is-i-would-rather-without-an-infinitive-immediately-following-it-correct).

Comment: Another related question, [“would rather” + subject + past subjunctive](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169250/would-rather-subject-past-subjunctive).